# how to display media play video picture in Android

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

My android activity use mediaplay to play rtsp streaming, when switch tabhost, I use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` in OnPaused and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in onResume. so the streaming play surface does not display in other surface interface. but `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` function will
tiggle surfaceCreate function reloaded and the Mediaplay will continue play without Video Picture.
it seems that Mediaplay cannot found new surface.
How to resolve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reset surface when surface view be recreated.U can call mediaplayer.setSurface(Surface surface) or mediaplayer.setDisplay(SurfaceHolder sh).
pls try this.

Comment: Thanks for your response,I have call this code in surfaceCreate fucntion,but it does not work.